# Como abrir la ventana de depuración de visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Tengo ya en modo depuración mi proyecto y quiero visualizar el valor de mis variables, pero no sé que ventana se tiene que mostrar para que pueda ver todo ese proceso.

**Mi proyecto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Lo que quiero**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: todas las pestañas estan dentro de la opcion de menu ver :/

Comment: Hola @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal , Como menciona gbianchi es en ver ("Watch") , agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al iniciar tu proyecto en modo de depuración, puedes seleccionar la variable que deseas y mediante botón derecho del "mouse" abrir el menú contextual en donde seleccionarías "Add Watch":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se abrirá una ventana donde puedes visualizar el valor de tus variables:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te sugiero revisar :

[Primer vistazo al depurador de Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019)

Comment: To open the Autos window, while debugging, select Debug > Windows > Autos, or press Ctrl+Alt+V > A.

To open the Locals window, while debugging, select Debug > Windows > Locals, or press Alt+4.

Comment: Gracias por la info :)